# FLASK: The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I keep getting "The method is not allowed for the requested URL"
Sorry if the code looks badly written but I am still a beginner and yeah.
I hope you can find what mistake I made and help me fix it !
Thank you in advance

Python code :

```
@app.route("/register/student", methods=["POST"])
def student_register_post():
    # handle post data
    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']
    course = request.form['course']
    #check if there is input in both fields
    if(email!="" and password!=""):
    # check if user exists
        if database.get_user_by_email(email) is not None:
            # print(database.get_user_by_email(email))
            return "An account with this email already exists."

        # create and add user
        tuser = User(email, password, course)
        database.add_user(tuser)

        # automatically login user
        login_user(tuser)

        return redirect('/protected_place')
    else:
        return redirect('/register/student')
```

HTML form:

````
    <form id="form" action="/register" method="post">
        <div id=inputs>
            <label id="courses_label" for="course"><b>Course</b></label>
            <select name="course" id="course" form="form" required>
                <option value="11A">11A</option>
                <option value="11A">11B</option>
                <option value="11A">11C</option>
                <option value="11A">11D</option>
            </select>
            <label><b>E-mail</b></label>
            <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Ex: mail@notgmail.com"/>
            

            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Ex: 123456 (please don't use that)"/>

        </div>
        <input id=register_button type="submit" name="register_button" value="Register">
    </form>```
````

Comment: Is the `action` correct? I see `@app.route('/register/student')` but your form action is trying to reach `/register`

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the issue all along !!